# Is there any difference between $!model and !$model in velocity?

Tags: velocity

Is there any difference between `!$model` and `$!model` in velocity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  `$!model` is quiet notation. If `$!model` renders as a null value in the context, then instead of seeing "$model" in the output, you will see "".

`!$model` is simply a "!" followed by however "$model" renders. **Except**, when you do `!$model` in a directive like: `#if( !$model )`, in which case, the "!" means "not" and negates the boolean value of `$model`.